# How to upgrade webpack from v1 to v4?

Tags: webpack, react-redux, babeljs

> Package.json file (this is not full file I have cleared some data)

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --content-base . --history-api-fallback",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "lint": "eslint app/.; exit 0",
    "fix": "eslint --fix app/.; exit 0"
  },
  "author": "abc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.1.1",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "net": false,
    "fs": false,
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

> Below is my `webpack.config.babel.js` file

```
import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname+ '/app/index.html',
    filename:'index.html', 
    inject:'body',
})


const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
}

console.log(1, PATHS.build)

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === "production"
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env' : {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
    }
})

const base = {
    entry:[
        PATHS.app,
    ],
    output : {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename:'/index_bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders : [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
            {test:/\.css$/, loader:'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'},
            {include: /\.json$/, loaders: ["json-loader"]}
        ]
    }, 
    plugins:[
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'lib', to: 'fontello'}])
    ],
    resolve: {
        root:path.resolve('./app')
    }
}


const developmentConfig = {
    devtool:'source-map',
    devServer:{
        contentBase:PATHS.build,
        hot:true,
        inline:true,
        progress:true,
    },
    plugins:[HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
}

const productionConfig = {
    devtool:'cheap-module-source-map',
    plugins:[HtmlWebpackPluginConfig, productionPlugin]
}

export default Object.assign({}, base, 
    isProduction === true ? productionConfig:developmentConfig)
```

I have tried and followed the Documentation from https://webpack.js.org/migrate/3/

But I got error on console

> webpack: Failed to compile.

I changed the below changes on webpack config file:

```
module: {
        rules : [
            {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},

            {
                test:/\.css$/, 
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                ]

            }
        ]
    }, 
    plugins:[
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'lib', to: 'fontello'}]),

        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true
        })

    ],
```

So, How can I upgrade webpack from 1 to 4 in my working project?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to upgrade to v4 (not only to v3), you also need to follow https://webpack.js.org/migrate/4/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).